# Eclipse SWT label not showing within Composite

Tags: eclipse, swt

My label is not showing up as expected in the codes below without setting the bound.
I am creating a Composite within the shell as I only want the background image to appear within this composite.

In this case what should the bound be? Can I get an optimal bound based on the text of the label?

```
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText("Header);

Composite main = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
main.setBounds(10, 5, 775, 505);
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/bg.png");
Image bg = new Image(display, is);
main.setBackgroundImage(bg);        
main.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);

Label label = new Label(main, SWT.NONE);            
//label.setBounds(0, 0, 400,100);           // not showing if commented away
label.setText("Label 1");
```

Comment: Did you try `main.pack()` or `shell.pack()`?

Comment: Moreover you don't seem to use a layout. See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html for an overview.

Comment: I thought I read it somewhere that Composite is by default GridLayout. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Haven't heard that yet and the Javadoc does not mention it, not meaning that it is wrong. Did any of the `pack()` calls work?

Comment: The code works for me with and without the commented `label.setBounds(0, 0, 400,100);`. I am on Win7, Eclipse 3.7.2 and JDK 1.6_b30.

Comment: There is no default layout for coompistes, you should set one. I think you're confusing with `GridLayoutData`: if you don't set one on the label, the GridLayout uses default values of the layout data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on Linux (Eclipse 3.6.2, Java 1.6.0.26):

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Header");

        Composite main = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        Image bg = new Image(display, "resources/bg.png");
        main.setBackgroundImage(bg);
        main.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);

        Label label = new Label(main, SWT.NONE);    
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        label.setText("Label 1");

        main.pack();
        main.setBounds(10, 5, 775, 505);
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Baz, many thanks for your help. I input your code in and it works. It realise that main.setBounds need to be called after you have added all the components into the Composite. My initial code is that it is set straight after declaration, which leads to this problem. I also learnt that no matter how much you set the width/height in setBounds, it will resize to the 'optimal' size after calling pack()!